# How to wrap a class between each 2 form fields in checkout page magento2

Tags: magento2

I have checkout form fields First Name , Last Name , Country , postal code

I need to wrap fields like this

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">Firstname field</div>
<div class="col-md-6">Lastname field</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">Country field</div>
<div class="col-md-6">Postalcode field</div>
</div>
```

I have added col-md-6 by overriding the Magento UI "`Magento_Ui/templates/form`" form.html there i have added col-md-6 so for each fields now this class is added. I'm not sure how to add class row for each 2 fields.

Please let me know if someone worked on this thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe what you are looking?

Comment: i need to redesign the checkout form wrapping inside the row and col-md-6 container , i have added the col-md-6 class for each field not sure how to wrap row class for each 2 field as a fieldset

Comment: I got the solution from the below link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114746/magento2-change-shipping-address-layout-on-checkout-page